# *_dpbusd_epi32 or *_maddubs_epi16 equivalent on ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm looking to port some `x86` intrinsics code to ARM but I am struggling to find the correct resources. When developing `x86` code, I mostly use this website for documentation: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ . Is there an `ARM` equivalent somewhere out there?

In particular I'm interested to find equivalents to the *`_dpbusd_epi32` or *`_maddubs_epi16` intrinsics (I'm not too fussed for having `unsigned`x`signed`, it could also be `signed`x`signed`)?

Comment: I don't think there is an exact equivalent. I'd look into the `vmull*` and `vmlal*` instructions for getting `s8*s8 --> s16` multiplications (how to actually use them really depends on what you actually want to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest reference page that Arm has at the moment is this one:

https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics

It's functional, but missing many of the useful search features of the Intel one.